# How to set value option instead of index of array in ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I use next construction for `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="month.id as month.value for month in data.dateList.years"
```

It gives me selcet list with value:

```
<option value="0" label="2016">2016</option>
```

How I can set 2016 instead `value = "0"` for each option?

Comment: Could you show us what your `data.dateList.years` looks like?

Comment: `data.dateList.years` contains 2015

Comment: cool, so what do you get when you do `console.log(data.dateList.year)` ?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="month.value as month.value for month in year track by month.value"
            ng-model="selectedValue"></select>
        <br/>
        Month is: {{ selectedValue }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.year = 
     [{id: 1, value: "January"}, 
      {id: 1, value: "February"}];
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/Ldeq26zv/) to see it running

Comment: This is not what I need. `ng-model="selectedValue"` would be integer `id`

Comment: Set `selectedValue`  to 1. It possible select January

Comment: @Faud I don't understand what  value do you want in selectedValue. Can you show us your data.dateList.years?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `month.id` use `month.value`

```
ng-options="month.value as month.value for month in data.dateList.years"
```

Comment: @Faud -- The `value` attribute will not reflect the actual value in the inspector, if that is how you are checking it.

Comment: But I can set `ng-model` like as: `ng-model="2015"` and it whold be select option with value 2015,

Comment: @Faud -- With my syntax, if you make a choice, is the value inside the `ngModel` reflected correctly?\

Answer (score 0):

Try using `month.value` instead of `month.id` in your `ng-options`